# Searching for a VM?

Tags: operating-system, vm

I would like to know if there is a app/ etc. thats makes possible to use multiple smartphone operating systems on device. To be precise: Is how to get an VM. Are there any apps or other posiblilities.

Or other stuff for andriod similar to "Bluestacks for Windows-Phone"

Answer (score 0):

QEMU is the only thing that does what you're asking for, at the moment. The download is available through XDA, http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1459153

Comment: No it shouldn't root access